# Django Custom User Model - admin customization

Tags: django, authentication, django-custom-user

So, I was making a custom user model, and to be able to change the password using the admin page I did this on the UserAdminChangeForm, is it wrong? I mean dealing with the security.

```
password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_(
            "Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this "
            "user’s password, but you can change the password using "
            '<a href="../password">this form</a>.'
        ),
    )
```

Comment: in your admin pannel on the `top right`, to the left of the `logout` there is `change password` link

Comment: yes, there is but, if a superuser wants to change the password of other users using the admin panel how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

if a superuser wants to change the password of other users using the admin panel they can use this endpoint: `/admin/auth/user/123/password/`, where `123` is the user's id.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to make here by using my own custom user. Here is the full code:- https://github.com/mohaali482/django-custom-email-user